# Module for unique visitors count

Tags: algorithm, module, stream, statistics

I got this on the job interview:

> Let’s assume that you got the task: to write a module, on input of which an infinite stream of IP-addresses of site visitors will be
> directed .
>
> In any moment of time module should be able to answer quickly, how
> many unique users are collected (uniqueness is specified by IP
> address). How would you describe the method of solving this question (in details)
> on the condition that:
>
> a) it needs to get exact amount of unique visitors
>
> b) approximate value with small inaccuracy not more than 3-4% is acceptable

What solutions do you see here? I've found several whitepapers about stream algorithms but I don't know if it's appliable in this case or not:

[http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~satishr/cs270/sp11/rough-notes/Streaming.pdf](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Esatishr/cs270/sp11/rough-notes/Streaming.pdf)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count-distinct_problem

Comment: If I was given that task, I would point out that requirements a) and b) are contradictory.  Then I would ask how much memory I had ... and how long the "infinite" stream really was.

Comment: Let's assume that RAM is 8 Gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only had to deal with 32-bit IPv4 addresses, you could use the simple solution (proposed by [@Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c)) of a bit vector of 2<sup>32</sup> bits (half a gigabyte). With that, you can maintain a precise count of unique addresses.

But these days, it is necessary to consider 128-bit IPv6 addresses, which is far too large a namespace to be able to use a bit-vector. If you only need an approximate count, though, you can use a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), which requires `k` bits per entry, for some small value of `k` related to the expected number of false positives you are prepared to accept. A false positive will cause a unique ip address to be uncounted, so the proportion of false positives is roughly the expected inaccuracy of a count.

As the linked Wikipedia page mentions, using 10 bits per entry is expected to keep the false positive percentage to less than one percent; with 8 GB of memory, you could maintain a Bloom filter with about 6.8 thousand million entries.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions you found are definitely appliable

For (a) I would have a counter for total unique IPs and would create a Hash in which the key would be the IP Address, you need to store every single IP address si
  That way whenever you receive an IP you check if it is already in the Hash and if its not you store it in there and increase the counter by one.

On the other hand for (b) I would use a Hashing function on the IPs themselves to compact them even further and then insert them on a smaller or more efficient Hash. This way the probability of a collision exists, but you also gain some performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2^32 unique IPv4 addresses.

So implement an array of 2^32 booleans whose indexes correspond to the IP addresses.  Each time you get a visit:

```
ip_index = convert_ip_to_32bit_integer(ip)
if !seen[ip_index]:
    seen[ip_index] = true
    nos_unique_visitors++
```

This requires 2^29 bytes of memory (i.e. 0.5Gb) assuming that you pack the booleans 8 per byte.

Comment: You assume that there are no IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is not IPV6 adresses, an IPV4 address is encoded using 4 bytes 255.255.255.255. Which gives us 32 bits.

You could use a binary tree with 32 levels to store the ip address which will let you know if an ip exists in the tree, insert it quickly and easily, ...
Number of operations to find an ip will then *approximatively* be something near 32*2.

You could prefer to use a Trie tree, with 8 levels, each one storing 4 bits. Maximum number of operations will be, with a number of operation of 8*16.

This will be a cheaper method than allowing memory for a full array, and a Trie can also be used for IPV6 with less costs.